# What is the most efficient way to convert a short string into a 32 bit integer?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, integer, constexpr

For many purposes, short strings/char arrays packed into an unsigned 32-bit integer are pretty useful, since they can be compared at one go with a simple integer comparison and be used in `switch` statements, while still maintaining a bit of human readability.

The most common way to convert these short strings to 32-bit integers is to shift/or:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t quadchar( const char* _str ) 
{

    uint32_t result = 0;

    for( size_t i=0; i<4; i++ )
    {
        if( _str[i] == 0 )
           return result;
        result = (result << 8) | _str[i];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Strings, which are too long, are truncated.

So far so good, but this has to be done on runtime, which costs a bit of time.
Would it be also possible to do this on compile time?

Comment: With C++14 and later you just need to add `constexpr` to your function. There is already an answer showing how to do this (namely recursively) for C++11. For C++03 it's practically impossible to get a good syntax, but one C++03 solution is source code preprocessing via some scripting.

Comment: The union method would be undefined behavior, and the result depends on the endianness of the CPU.

Comment: @Barmar: true, thx. I removed this passage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need of a detail helper function: you can use default values.

And there is no need for a double ternary operator: you can make all with a single test

```
std::uint32_t inline constexpr quadchar (char const * input, 
                                         std::size_t idx = 0U,
                                         std::uint32_t result = 0U) 
 {
   return (idx < 4U) && *input
      ? quadchar(input+1, idx+1U, (result << 8) | *input)
      : result;
 }
```

But, to make it a little more portable and generic, I suggest

1) use `sizeof()` instead of `4` for the `idx` limit

2) use `CHAR_BIT` instead of `8` for the `result` shift (remember to include "`<climits>`")

3) use a template type (defaulted to `std::uint32_t`, if you want) for the `result` type.

Something like

```
template <typename I = std::uint32_t>
constexpr inline I ichar (char const * input, 
                          I result = 0U,
                          std::size_t idx = 0U)
 {
   return (idx < sizeof(I)) && *input
      ? ichar(input+1, idx+1U, (result << CHAR_BIT) | *input)
      : result;
 }
```

that you can call

```
constexpr auto u32 = ichar(ptr);
```

when you want a `std::uint32_t`, or (by example)

```
constexpr auto u64 = ichar<std::uint64_t>(ptr);
```

for other returned types.

Comment: Thank you. The `sizeof()` and template ideas are very good. I'm not so sure about `CHAR_BIT`. In case `CHAR_BIT` != 8, the result will differ to that of an 8 bit char because of the different shifting; I think this is less portable instead of more. It would be perhaps better to do an additional `& 0xff` instead with the input char. The helper function was implemented to hide the `result` and `input` parameters, because they make no sense for the user. But of course default parameters are also ok.

Comment: @user2328447 - I've some doubts about `CHAR_BIT` too (by example: exist `std::uint32_t` in a platform with `CHAR_BIT = 12`?) but take in count that if `CHAR_BIT > 8` (`8` is the minimum), every char in `input` is with `CHAR_BIT` bits; so with `(result << 8) | *input` you have a collision (or-bitted) of last bits in preceding char and the first in `*input`.

Comment: @user2328447 - and yes: the `& 0xff` idea could be a good alternative solution; take in count that, this way, you loose the use of some bits in chars (in case `CHAR_BITS > 8`) and manage the right bits in `input` chars could be difficult and platform dependent.

Answer (score 0):

As of C++11, it's possible to do this on compile time with zero costs on runtime, using the [constexpr specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr).

```
namespace Internal 
{
    uint32_t inline constexpr quadchar( char const *_input, 
        uint8_t _idx, uint32_t _result ) 
    {
        return _idx == 4 ? _result 
            : *_input ? quadchar ( _input+1, _idx + 1, (_result << 8) | *_input ) 
                : _result;
    }
}

uint32_t inline constexpr quadchar( char const *_input ) {
    return Internal::quadchar( _input, 0, 0 );
}
```

I have placed the implementation overload into an internal namespace to hide it from the user. The syntax is not as nice as in the above runtime example, since you can't use `if` in `constexpr`, but I think it's worth it.

Comment: The same portability warning that applied to the question applies to this answer.  It may be that if the converted string is never persisted or sent over the network, it doesn't matter.  A call to `honl()` may be judicious here.  On many CPUs is compiles into very few instructions- possibly just one.

Comment: Sorry, I don't exactly understand what you mean. What is not portable here? As far as I can see, everything should be portable, and non-endianess-dependent. And what is `honl()`, please? Could not find anything about it.